# TF2 Backpack items not showing up — stuck on loading

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2

I can't access any of my items in my TF2 backpack when I'm in the game. This happens on every page of my backpack:

[image: Loading animations in every tile.]

Is there any fix to this?

Comment: It *could* be because the media.steampowered.com server (which is where all the backpack images are stored) went down while you were checking your backpack.  All I can suggest is to try again later.

Comment: @Powerlord My first page of my backpack shows up, then when I click another page none of the items show up (looks like the picture above) and then when I go back to the first page it looks like the same thing. So none of my items have shown up. I have waited for weeks now and re-installed tf2 but the problem still persists.

Comment: @VishwaIyer - I'd put that down to caching - It's managed to get your first page of items, but not the rest. Is this still an issue?

Comment: Yes it is. I've resorted to re-downloading the game (again), so we'll see what happens.

Comment: @Robotnik Ok reinstalling the game didn't help. The same problem is showing up. It's even worse now, none of my backpack icons will show up.

Comment: I have reinstalled the game a second time. I have removed any custom files (huds, sounds, cfgs, etc.), but the item icons still don't show up. I get the same problem as shown in the picture.

Comment: Any firewalls, proxy's or parental controls installed (or any other app that can block internet access)?

Comment: @aman207 There aren't any.

Comment: Are you able to view your TF2 inventory in your steam profile?  Could you link us to it?

Comment: Here's my inventory: http://steamcommunity.com/id/vishiswoz/inventory/. I can view my inventory there. I can't view it in the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with this. While playing a map, I discovered this command that might help you:

1. Open up Developer console
2. Now type in `tf_time_loading_item_panels 0.0005`
3. It might lag a bit, but it will then load up your items

Answer (score 1):

I have also experienced this issue occasionally, and it's highly likely that the TF2 Item servers were under heavy load, not responding or even just simply down at the time you attempted to load your backpack.

If this bug happens again, you can check the status of the TF2 Item servers on the [TF2 Trade Lists site](http://status.tf2lists.com/) or various other TF2-centric sites that regularly check up on the servers. If you continue to experience issues over an extended period of time, try contacting [Steam Support](https://support.steampowered.com/).

Answer (score -1):

I found a fix:

1. Back up all your custom files or any another files you want to keep.
2. Delete the TF2 folder `ProgramFiles/Steam/steamapps/common/TeamFortress2`
3. Delete local content.
4. Reinstall TF2 and put back your custom files or anything else.

This will completely reset TF2 and fix your backpack icons.

Enjoy.

Comment: No, this is not a simple reinstall, this is a complete powerwash.

Comment: I have reinstalled tf2 before, but i haven't deleted anything, but i'm still getting this error. are you sure that this will work?

Comment: Removing the local content dose not re install the game, it simply removes the active files being used by steam, deleting the game folder removes it completely on steam. Don't worry, this wont delete your backpack or anything crazy, all that stuff is on the cloud. It will create basically a brand new version of tf2 for you to use. It worked with me. I did have a few problems with the custom folder but that was on me, if it dose not work however then please, be sure to tell me

Comment: Yes this didn't work for me. Still cannot see my backpack items.